# javascript curry example in async.js library

Tags: javascript, currying, async.js

i was reading the source code for async.js library and with in that i found a function called 'only_once' and then i tried some examples to make it clear how it works, but i can't figure out what is wrong with my examples cause they simply do not behave the way they should. here is my code:

```
function only_once(fn) {
    var called = false;
    return function () {
        if (called) throw new Error('Callback was already called.');
        called = true;
        fn.apply(this, arguments);
    };
 }

 // my example code
 var add = function (a, b) { return a + b; };
 var add_once = only_once(add);

 var a = add_once(1, 3);
 console.log(a);       // this prints undefined not 4, what the hell ?????
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`only_once()` isn't currently doing anything with the result of `fn` -- `add`, in this case.

It should provide the `return` value from `fn` as its own:

```
return fn.apply(this, arguments);
```

```
// vs.
fn.apply(this, arguments);
```

In context:

```
// ...
return function () {
    if (called) throw new Error('Callback was already called.');
    called = true;
    return fn.apply(this, arguments);
};
// ...
```

---

Within `async.js`, the `return` value isn't being used, so it doesn't have to be provided.

The asynchronous functions the library is designed for instead accept callback functions as arguments to be invoked later and passed the results.

`only_once` is just preventing these from being invoked multiple times:

```
function asyncFunc(callback) {
    setTimeout(callback, 100); // callback invoked
    setTimeout(callback, 200); // Uncaught Error: Callback was already called.
}

asyncFunc(only_once(function (value) {
    console.log('callback invoked');
}));
```

Comment: wow, that's really thorough, thank you so much, but still there is one thing that i don't quite understand, how can you use the passed arguments in the call back? cause if you console.log(arguments) in the callback without the existence of a 'return' statement it is undefined.